# What is the Scope of Bean declared in @ModelAttribute annotation

Tags: java, spring-mvc, modelattribute

I have a table having 40 columns and one bean corresponding to that table. But on page I am displaying only 10 fields. When the page is rendered, by debugging, I can see the bean is getting populated by all fields from the table and I am adding it in Model using `model.addAttribute("emp", emp)` . But after changing some fields on page, when I submit the page again, I see only those fields are getting populated who are appearing on the page. Rest are not though the bean is in "session" scope.

I have one controller which is called when I submit the page. Thats something like below

```
@RequestMapping({"/update.html"})
public String updateData(@ModelAttribute("emp") Employee emp){
    // All fields of Employee bean are not getting populated
}
```

I wrote in JSP something like below.

```
<jsp:useBean class="com.Employee" id="emp"
    scope="request" />
```

Note :- I tested with scope="session" as well.

So my question is, Even after putting bean in SESSION scope, why I am not getting it in my controller. So is @ModelAttribute changing my bean scope any how??

Comment: Since I using jQuery as well so for meanwhile I put all those fields in JSP, made them hidden and my bean is getting populated with all the fields in my controller. Is it the right way????

Answer (score 2):

`@ModelAttribute` on a method argument essentially binds the model(what you have submitted through the fields) with the type (in this case `Employee`) and exposes this bound type as a model that you can use in your jsp. It is not a Spring bean at all at this point, just an object scoped to the request.

Now, on how to pre-populate your bean, a cleaner approach may be to define another method in your controller annotated with `@ModelAttribute`, that is responsible for loading up your model from the database this way:

```
@ModelAttribute("emp")
public Employee loadModelAttributes(@RequestParam("empid") int empid){
    // return employee fully populated..
}
```

This will ensure that in your controller method only the fields that you are submitting from the UI are now updated into the base `Employee` that you have populated from the DB, this way you don't have to hold things in the hidden variables.

```
@RequestMapping({"/update.html"})
public String updateData(@ModelAttribute("emp") Employee emp){
    // All fields of Employee bean are not getting populated
}
```

Comment: Upvoted for another approach but this is not wht I want. I think, writing @ModelAttribute("emp") before method and writing model.addAttribute("emp") IN the method both are same. Second, when the page gets rendered my bean is populating properly(no issue there). Problem arises when I submit the page. That time I am not seeing all non-displaying fields in my bean. I want all fields in my bean to be populated.

Comment: @Jai, this is the expected behavior with Spring MVC, when you specify a type as a parameter to a `@RequestMapping` method, the fields that you submit in your form will be bound to that type. Now when you annotate that field with @ModelAttribute it will create a model with that name for you. Additionally if you want to prepopulate the model and then update with what you submit on you, you can do what I have suggested - which is to have another method with `@ModelAttribute` annotation which can populate the content based on DB.

Comment: Thanks @Biju but again, I am not facing any problem in pre-populating the bean. The code that I showed up here is having Employee as an example that might be giving you impression of that I am trying something at home. But its not like that. This is what I am facing in company and I can not change the architecture of application. What you are suggesting is good but not practical in my case.

Answer (score 0):

As @Biju stated, the model attribute parameter is a new object, separate from the object in the model. The model attribute parameter is filled with the data from the page, but is not intialized with the data from the model object.

The new data from the model attribute parameter must be copied into the bean that you have placed into the session.