# How to force data as part of form submission with Spring + Thymeleaf + JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, thymeleaf

tldr; I would like an entire object to be persistent in form submission, and not just the parts of the object which were added to the Thymeleaf template.

Basically, I'm performing a database query in one endpoint and filling in a form with several fields from the JPA Entity result, showing the data currently in the database.  However, when I submit the form, only the fields which were displayed on the page via Thymeleaf are sent in the form data.  I want the entire object, not just the parts which are displayed, **because I need the ID field which will identify which record to update** with the form is submitted (when user hits the "save" button).  *How is this generally done in Spring?*

Here is some code:

```
<form id="form" th:action="@{/labor/save}" th:object="${laborSession}" method="post">
    <!-- various input fields and select lists -->
</form>
```

The Entity which was sent added to the Model when the page is loaded:

```
"laborSession": {
    "OverTime": 0,
    "TripTypeFactor": 0.5,
    "EmergencyCall": false,
    "LaborDate": "2020-11-12",
    "TripMileageRate": 1.2,
    "TripMileageTotal": 36,
    "LaborTotal": 962.5,
    "LaborRate": 110,
    "JobNumber": 99998,
    "TripLaborRate": 110,
    "LastModified": "2020-11-25 14:56:06.0",
    "LaborID": 1,
    "CustomerNumber": 100279,
    "PersonalVehicle": false,
    "RTMiles": 60,
    "LaborHrs": 8.75,
    "DriveTime_EMT": 0,
    "DriveTime_RT": 0,
    "InvoiceNumber": 0,
    "LaborClass": "SCALES",
    "PayPeriod": 1507,
    "TechName": "TYLER DOEPEL",
    "TripMileage": 30,
    "DriveTime_SHT": 0,
    "RegularTime": 8,
    "LaborPerformed": "THIS IS JUST A TEST LABOR ENTRY\r\nLINE #2\r\nLINE #3",
    "TripLaborHrs": 0.75,
    "EmergencyTime": 0,
    "BaseOfOperation": "NASHVILLE",
    "TripLaborTotal": 82.5,
    "LaborType": "MAINTENANCE",
    "LaborCompleted": false,
    "Sun_HolidayTime": 0,
    "Total": 998.5,
    "TripType": "TRUCK HALF TRIP",
    "DiscountedTime": 0,
    "JobRowGUID": "64AAB2C8-3BFA-449A-B722-0BCD10283EE6",
    "DriveTime_OT": 0,
    "PersonalMiles": 30
}
```

This is the Entity object returned from the form submission, which is clearly missing values.  The only values I receive are the ones which were explicitly referenced in the form.

```
"laborEntity": {
    "OverTime": 0,
    "LaborClass": "SCALES",
    "TechName": "TYLER DOEPEL",
    "LaborDate": "2020-11-12",
    "DriveTime_SHT": 0,
    "RegularTime": 8,
    "LaborPerformed": "THIS IS JUST A TEST LABOR ENTRY\r\nLINE #2\r\nLINE #3",
    "EmergencyTime": 0,
    "BaseOfOperation": "NASHVILLE",
    "LaborType": "MAINTENANCE",
    "Sun_HolidayTime": 0,
    "TripType": "TRUCK HALF TRIP",
    "DiscountedTime": 0,
    "DriveTime_EMT": 0,
    "DriveTime_RT": 0,
    "DriveTime_OT": 0,
    "PersonalMiles": 30
}
```

When I submit, the `laborSession` object only contains the fields which I displayed, as I stated before.  How can I submit all parts of the `th:object` without littering extra hidden fields with data attributes all over the code in the page/template?  Is there not a nice, neat way to get the full object back when the submission is processed?

By the way, unless I add the ID as an attribute in a tag on the template, I get this nice Exception from the EntityRepository (JPA) which indicates that the ID was null in the Entity when trying to `save()` the record:

```
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.m.j.db.entity.LaborEntity
```

Answer (score 0):

> The only values I receive are the ones which were explicitly referenced in the form.
>
> (...)
>
> How can I submit all parts of the `th:object` without littering extra hidden fields with data attributes all over the code in the page/template?

You can't. I don't see how it could work otherwise as Thymeleaf is a templating engine [not a magic data binder](https://www.jakubch.eu/articles/2020_11_26/what_thymeleaf_is_not.html).

Luckily you can handle the situation on the backend side. An elegant approach was described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21399618/5684265) to another question. As follow:

1. Enpoint providing the form view accepts `LaborID` as request param or path variable. Let's select the request param approach for the example:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/labor", params = "laborID")
public String getLabor() {
   return "labor_form_template";
}
```

2. You provide your `laborSession` to a model using dedicated method, aware of `laborID`:

```
@ModelAttribute("laborSession")
public YourLaborSessionClass loadLaborSession(@RequestParam("laborID") int laborID){ 
    return yourLaborRepository.findByLaborID(laborID); // or whatever source it has...
}
```

3. Endpoint handling the form submission accepts `laborID` in the same way as in point 1.:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/labor", params = "laborID")
public String saveLabor(@ModelAttribute(name = "laborSession") YourLaborSessionClass laborSession) {
   // At this point laborSession object received from @ModelAttribute method is enriched with input data.
   // All fields available in form are updated whereas other fields are as before.
}
```

4. After making your endpoints `laborID` aware, reflect the change in your form within `th:action` attribute.

```
<form id="form" th:action="@{/labor(laborID=${laborSession.laborID})}" th:object="${laborSession}" method="post">
```